# Making items in a grid or flexbox have an equal dynamic number of columns per row

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to show a list of items responsively on all screen sizes. I'm gonna illustrate exactly what I mean:

```
# on a screen with enough real estate to fit all items:
[ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ]

# on a screen that can fit 4 to 7 items:
[ 1 2 3 4 ]
[ 5 6 7 8 ]

# on a screen that can only fit 3 items:
[ 1 2 3 ]
[ 4 5 6 ]
[ 7 8   ]

# OR better
[ 1 2 3 ]
[ 4 5 6 ]
[  7 8  ]
```

So on and so forth.

I've tried to achieve this using flexbox: `flex-flow: row wrap` and using grid: `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(80px, 1fr));` but no matter what, the result is something along these lines:

```
# Using flex box
[ 1 2 3 4 5 6 ]
[ 7         8 ]

# Using grid
[ 1 2 3 4 5 6 ]
[ 7 8         ]
```

Can you guys think of a solution?? Thanks

**EDIT**
Here's a snippet for the most curios ones. Please note that in order to fully see what I mean, resize your window, so that **5** and only **5** items fit into a single row. In these two examples first row contains 5 columns, second row contains 3 columns. What I want is to have 4 and 4 columns WHILE 5 items fit in the first row.

```css
div.using-flex ul {
  background: #fc0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

div.using-flex li {
  background: rgba(120, 0, 200, 0.5);
  list-style: none;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 4px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 7px;
  min-width: 80px;
}

div.using-grid ul {
  background: #fc0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(80px, 1fr));
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

div.using-grid li {
  background: tomato;
  list-style: none;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 4px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 7px;
  min-width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="using-flex">
    <ul>
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>Item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
      <li>Item4</li>
      <li>Item5</li>
      <li>Item6</li>
      <li>Item7</li>
      <li>Item8</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div class="using-grid">
    <ul>
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>Item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
      <li>Item4</li>
      <li>Item5</li>
      <li>Item6</li>
      <li>Item7</li>
      <li>Item8</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: No...that's not how CSS-grid works (or flexbox) you'll need media queries or javascript.

Comment: Well I don't like using JS for something like this, but you're right about media queries. It's almost a perfect solution. But I just wanted to make sure that it's not possible using those two mentioned methods first (just out of curiosity mostly). Thanks for the input @Paulie_D

Comment: Can you show your code, and explain - with clear steps - how to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @DavidThomas Done!

Comment: Do you know minimal width of blocks?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this:

The HTML

```
<body>
    <h1>Flex</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="flex">
        <div class="item">FlexBox</div>
        <div class="item">FlexBox</div>
        <div class="item">FlexBox</div>
        <div class="item">FlexBox</div>
        <div class="item">FlexBox</div>
        <div class="item">FlexBox</div>
        <div class="item">FlexBox</div>
        <div class="item">FlexBox</div>      
    </div>
    <h1>Grid</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="item">Grid</div>
        <div class="item">Grid</div>
        <div class="item">Grid</div>
        <div class="item">Grid</div>
        <div class="item">Grid</div>
        <div class="item">Grid</div>
        <div class="item">Grid</div>
        <div class="item">Grid</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The SCSS

```
* {
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}
.item {
    padding: 1rem;
    border: 1px dashed rgba(black, .4);
}
.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    .item {
        margin:10px;
        flex:1 1 auto;
    }
}

//OR

.grid {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(4rem, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 1.5rem;
}
```